# Download a CSV file from a lightning component using a button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, static-resources

I'm trying to add a button Download CSV Template where I'll connect the button with a static resource. So, when you click the button, the files downloads, user can open the file, fill and reupload to add products. Below is the screenshot where it should come.
[image: Location where I want the button]

But I'm not sure how I should do. Below is my modified code.

```
<aura:component description="VirtualCartComponent"
            controller="VirtualCartController"                                  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="data" type="ITC_VirtualCartLineItem__c"/>
<aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="deleteRows" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="quoteId" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="retUrl" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="isReadOnly" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="displayModal" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="channel" type="String" default="/event/VirtualCartEvent__e"/>
<aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Map"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
<aura:handler name="itemAddedEvent" event="c:VirtualCartEvent" action="{!c.handleVirtualCartEvent}"/>
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{! c.init }" />

<lightning:button name="Add Items" label="Add Items" disabled="{! v.isReadOnly }" iconName="action:edit" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleAddItems}"/>
<lightning:button name="Import CSV" label="Import CSV" disabled="{! v.isReadOnly }" iconName="action:upload" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleImportCsv}"/>
<lightning:button name="Process" label="Process" disabled="{! v.isReadOnly }" variant="success" iconName="action:approval" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleProcess}"/>
<lightning:button name="DownloadCSVTemplate" label="Download CSV Template" disabled="{! v.isReadOnly }" iconName="action:arrow_bottom" iconPosition="left" >
    <img src="/resource/CSV_Products_Template/application/vnd.ms-excel.csv" />
    <!--<a href="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0815t0000008SngAAE'}" target="_blank"/>-->   </lightning:button>
<lightning:button name="Delete" label="Delete" aura:id="deleteButton" disabled="{! v.isReadOnly }" class="hide" type="submit"
                  variant="destructive" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleMassDelete}"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.loaded }">

    <aura:set attribute="else">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" />
    </aura:set>
</aura:if>
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
<lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  fields="ITC_Processed__c"
                  recordUpdated="{! c.reloadView }"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.displayModal}">
    <div>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Meaningful description of the modal content" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeBtn}">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" variant="neutral"/>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                </header>

                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium alignLeft" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to process the virtual cart?</p>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button label="Yes"
                                      variant="brand" class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                      onclick="{!c.handleProcess}"/>
                    <lightning:button label="No"
                                      variant="brand" class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                      onclick="{!c.noBtn}"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<div style="min-height: 300px">
    <lightning:datatable
            enableInfiniteLoading="true"
            keyField="Id"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            data="{! v.data }"
            draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="{! v.isReadOnly }"
            selectedRows="{! v.selectedRows }"
            onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
            onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
            onrowselection="{! c.handleRowSelection }"
            showRowNumberColumn="false"/>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

I have not done any changes in Controller classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url of a static resource in aura using [$Resource.resourceName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm)

It's probably easiest to create a link with `<a href="{!$Resource.MyCsvFile}" download>Download CSV Template</a>` and use css to make the link look like a button.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Should I add any other attributes ? I see download doesn't have any value in your reply

Comment: It can be used without a value, but with a value it will suggest the value as a filename. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: Hi Alves,

I modified the lines and your suggestion helped me. Below lines with my colleague's help did the job
<lightning:button name="DownloadCSVTemplate" label="Download CSV Template" disabled="{!v.isReadOnly }"  iconName="action:download">
        <a href="{!$Resource.CSV_Products_Template}" label="DownloadCSVTemplate" download="LineItemsTemplate.csv">DownloadCSVTemplate</a>  
    </lightning:button>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) to implement this functionality. The main idea is to convert the Static Resource CSV into Base64 encoded String and pass it to the download method of download.js. Which will show the file download window upon the same screen by clicking the download button.

Here is a sample code you can refer to.

Aura Component

```
<aura:component controller="CSVController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:card>
        <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.downloadjs}"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Download CSV Template" onclick="{! c.downloadCSVFile }" />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Aura JS Controller

```
({
    downloadCSVFile : function(component) { 
        var action = component.get("c.getCSVFileAsBase64String");
        action.setCallback(this, function(action){
            var state = action.getState();
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                var strFile = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,"+action.getReturnValue();
                download(strFile, "csvtemplate.csv", "application/csv");
            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public class CSVController {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String getCSVFileAsBase64String() {
        List<StaticResource> resourceList = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'CSVTemplate'];
        return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(resourceList[0].Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saroj,

Your solution is very complex for me, thanks for your answer anyway. I solved the question.